# #LinkedIn unresponsive to API request

Tags: linkedin-api

We had a API with LinkedIn so that our internal intranet would display a closed LinkedIn discussion group. But then #linkedin changed their API rules. Ok, no problems, I was told by our development team to complete this form: https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply
But I have tried twice and never heard back. No response. LinkedIn customer service say they can't help because they only deal with sites and support related issues. So any ideas? It has been weeks and is driving me mad as it is giving our users a bad experience on their intranets. 
Thanks,
Jess

Answer (score 0):

Since the new changes to API there are to ways:
 1. is to do what you have done. But LinkedIn will turn you down. There is no gain for them in your closed group.

2. Create a new dummy company page. Make everyone who want to have access to the secret group admin of that company page and then make some code changes. And it will work.
3. There are tools that are 10 times better if you want to have a closed group.